# Android R, copy file from cache to downloads?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Since getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated, this code was working a couple of days ago, it failed this morning with an error saying open failed: EEXIST (File exists) but in the downloads folder it doesn't exist at all, I'm presuming some sort of update on my Android device broke something, as getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated how do replace it?

I've read about contentResolver, and read some examples;

val resolver = context.contentResolver
val contentValues = ContentValues()
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,"${mydeckio.deckName}.zip")
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/zip" )
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
val zipUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri))

Also OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE? I don't *really* want to open a UI and would rather just copy the file to /Downloads.

```
2021-10-10 10:40:36.185 19824-19824/com.rdesign.cardgame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rdesign.cardgame, PID: 19824
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/MelsDeckNoMedia.zip: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
        at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo(Utils.kt:236)
        at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo$default(Utils.kt:217)
        at com.rdesign.cardgame.ZipIOKt.zipDirectory(ZipIO.kt:99)
        at com.rdesign.cardgame.DeckIO.exportDeck(DeckIO.kt:661)
        at com.rdesign.cardgame.FragmentDeckOptionsSetupdeck.onViewCreated$lambda-1(fragment_deckoptions_setupdeck.kt:49)
        at com.rdesign.cardgame.FragmentDeckOptionsSetupdeck.$r8$lambda$vil11wD97koNonQCzCOxRbRSi0I(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.rdesign.cardgame.FragmentDeckOptionsSetupdeck$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EEXIST (File exists)
        at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8456)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236) 
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186) 
        at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo(Utils.kt:236) 
        at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo$default(Utils.kt:217) 
        at com.rdesign.cardgame.ZipIOKt.zipDirectory(ZipIO.kt:99) 
        at com.rdesign.cardgame.DeckIO.exportDeck(DeckIO.kt:661) 
        at com.rdesign.cardgame.FragmentDeckOptionsSetupdeck.onViewCreated$lambda-1(fragment_deckoptions_setupdeck.kt:49) 
        at com.rdesign.cardgame.FragmentDeckOptionsSetupdeck.$r8$lambda$vil11wD97koNonQCzCOxRbRSi0I(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.rdesign.cardgame.FragmentDeckOptionsSetupdeck$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16222) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137) 
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 









//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ZIP
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fun zipDirectory(context : Context, inputDir : File) : String {

    val outputZipFile = File.createTempFile("out", ".zip")

    ZipOutputStream(BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(outputZipFile))).use { zos ->
        inputDir.walkTopDown().forEach { file ->
            val zipFileName = file.absolutePath.removePrefix(inputDir.absolutePath).removePrefix("/")
            val entry = ZipEntry("$zipFileName${(if (file.isDirectory) "/" else "")}")
            zos.putNextEntry(entry)
            if (file.isFile) {
                file.inputStream().copyTo(zos)
            }

        }
    }

    mygame.toasty(context,"Archive Complete, Copying to Downloads")

    // TODO: Replace getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() - IS DEPRECATED!!!
    //val downloadFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()
    //outputZipFile.copyTo(File("${downloadFolder}/${mydeckio.deckName}.zip"),true)
    //outputZipFile.delete()
    
    return outputZipFile.name
}
```

Added exportDeck for more clarity. @CommonsWare

```
fun exportDeck(context : Context, tvLogView : TextView) {

    val tmppathrootfolder = createTempDirectory()
 
    // Zip the Deck and place it in app filesDir
    zipDirectory(context,File("$tmppathrootfolder"))

    // Delete Temporary Data
    //context.cacheDir.deleteRecursively()
    //deleteDir(File("$tmppathrootfolder"))
}
```

Some success, although I don't know why it's outputting a 0 byte file.

```
private fun copyZipFile(context : Context, factivity: FragmentActivity,pickerInitialUri: Uri,zipFileName : String) {

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/zip"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, zipFileName)
    }
    startActivityForResult(factivity,intent, CREATE_FILE,null)
}
```

Comment: We do not know how `exportDeck()` is calling `zipDirectory()`. From the error message, it would seem that perhaps your output file already exists, created by another app or by the user directly. You cannot overwrite files in `Downloads/`, including overwriting files created by previous installed copies of your app (that were later uninstalled). You seem to creating only one file, so you would not need `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, but rather `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: It's just a temporary directory in my apps cache folder, doesn't ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT opening a user interface?

Comment: "It's just a temporary directory in my apps cache folder" -- not according to your error. Your error is from trying to write to `Downloads/`. In your code, everything referencing `Downloads/` appears to be commented out. "doesn't ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT opening a user interface?" -- yes. That is the idea: let the **user** decide where on the **user's** device (or in the **user's** cloud storage) that the **user** wants you to put the **user's** content.

Comment: Commented out because that's where the crashing was accruing. Yeah I get it users choice I just don't like how the 'user interface' operates and I'm concerned that for example (off topic) selecting a file and choosing to select nothing and having to press back 3 times just to get back to the app is wrong implementation from my point of view, there should have been a cancel selection option, or pressing back sends you back to the app not up in the directory tree, but there isn't one, hence the attempted avoidance at using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: Some success, although I don't know why it's outputting a 0 byte file.

Comment: Then you should focus on ensuring that you are going to have a unique location to write your file to. That could be adding a timestamp or something to the filename. You could also try creating an app-specific directory in `Downloads`. FWIW, [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html) describes some of `Downloads` limitations on Android 10, and it links to [a sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/download-wrangler) showing the `MediaStore.Downloads` option.